# error C2065: 'IDD_ ' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am creating Class using MFC class wizard in VS 2008, Choosing Base class as CProperty Page, After finish wizard file created but i getting error in this line `enum { IDD = IDD_APPLICATION };`

```
Error : error C2065: 'IDD_APPLICATION ' : undeclared identifier
```

Comment: What is IDD_APPLICATION?

Comment: Are you including your resource header file ?

Comment: Add #include "resource.h"

Answer (score 3):

As cpx asked, have you included resource.h into the header file of the new class?

More importantly, have you created a dialog resource in your resource file with the id IDD_APPLICATION?

Comment: +1 seems like VS2012 doesn't add that include on older MFC projects.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have to change MFC Mode to "true", you find that on the properties page of your .rc file. (This helped me)